# How reset page title category magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, database, seo, page-title

I need reset page title all my category store.

How make phpmyadmin query?

Comment: Category titles? What do you mean with reset?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add the code below before `</layout>`:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle"><title>Your New Title</title></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Clean Magento and broser cache.